# Flask session cookie changes datatype

Tags: python, flask, session, session-cookies

I'm building a web application for a database in python with flask hosted on pythonanywhere.

By now the application has everything you might need for a version 1 including menu, forms, logging and a some basic user-authentication with flask-login.
Everything works fine as long as you start off with a fresh browser and don't switch users while in the same browser.

I was able to pinpoint the bug to the flask.session cookie.
Somehow this cookie, which basically behaves like a dictionary changes its type from `<class 'dict'>` to `<class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy'>`. I can still access it the same way as before, but the data between those two cookies is not the same which leads to some weird redirects.

The flask app is created as follows:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'SUPER SECRET'
app.config.update(SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE="None", SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True, REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE = True)
app.run(debug=False, threaded=True)
```

Printing the session to the console looks similiar to this. So far I was not able to identify under what circumstances the output changes

**Output 1**

```
 <SecureCookieSession {'Key1': 1, 
                       'Key2': [{'Subkey1': 'value1', 'Subkey2': 'value2'}], 
                       '_fresh': True, 
                       '_id': 'loooooooooongstring, 
                       '_user_id': 'someid'}>
```

**Output 2**

```
{'Key1': 2, 
 'Key2': [{'Subkey1': 'othervalue1', 'Subkey2': 'othervalue2'}]}
```

Since both Options behave like a dict it was hard to detect this anomaly. **I don't even really mind what I'm working with but the main issue here is that they dont hold the same values.**

At first I thought it could have something to do with the ominous `flask.session.modified = true` statement that needs to be called manually. But this is in place everywhere (probably overkill).

I'm open for suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Maybe I did something fundamentally wrong with the way the application is set up. For example the offline version doesn't seem to have this issue.

Maybe it is possible to identify both options and mirror them constantly?

**Edits**
The output of print(f'cookie_type: {type(cookie)}') and print(type(cookie)) is the same.

Comment: Its possible that the way you are calling the prints are calling both a `str` and a `repr` method which would show things differently (possible). To ensure they are the same data type, can you just try to print the data type `print(f'cookie_type: {type(cookie)}')` and see that its the same both times.  If it isn't then you'd want to write a function to properly serialize the data.

Comment: The same type is displayed

Comment: To ensure you always get a dict, I believe that `SecureCookie` object inherits from dict. So you should be able to do something like this. `cookie.__dict__` and that should always be the same type, which would be a dict. Also, if you share the WHOLE thing it would make it much easier to troubleshoot